# Сравнить два списка и выдать разницу delphi

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Здрайвтсуйте!
Необходимо сравнить два списка которые находятся в memo1, memo2 соответственно и выдать разницу в memo3,memo4.
Списки могут содержать как более 30тыс. так и 10 строк.
Циклами и регулярками выполняется долго.
Через stringlist и indexof в разы быстрее но хочется ещё быстрее используя потоки. Но проблема в том что я в потоках дерево.
В идеале было бы 30000 поделить на несколько потоков которые выполнялись бы паралельно.
Последовательность выдачи результата не важна.
Пожалуйста помогите!?
Это до чего я смог одуматься..

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type
  potok = class(TThread) // Унаследовали класс потока
  private
    str: string; // В разделе private описываются переменные с помощью которых
    nomer: Integer; // будем передавать значения между процедурами внутри потока
  protected
    procedure Execute; override; // Главная процедура потока, начинает работу после создания потока

  public
    procedure synchro; // в разделе public вы можете объявить процедуры какие только душе угодно
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean); // В implementation опишем конструкцию потока

  end;

var
  a: array [1 .. 10] of potok; // массив для хранения наших потоков
  srtli: array [1 .. 10] of string; // массив для хранения наших потоков
  Form1: TForm1;
  nom: Integer;

implementation

constructor potok.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  // Поток после создания будет приостановлен если true при создании, если false, то сразу начнёт работу.
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pot: Integer;
begin
  for pot := 1 to 2 do // цикл запускает 2 потока, которые изменяют заголовок формы
    a[pot] := potok.Create(false); // так же идёт добавление в массив, что бы потом уничтожить их по одному.
end;

{ potok }

procedure potok.Execute; // Главная процедура потока
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  synchronize(synchro);
  { for i := 0 to 10 do
    begin
    sleep(50);
    synchronize(synchro); // Вызываем процедуру synchro в единичном экземпляре
    end; }
end;

procedure potok.synchro; // Процедура потока, которая меняет загаловок form1
{ begin
  inc(nom);
  Form1.Memo2.Lines.Add('Поток делает своё дело - ' + inttostr(nom)); }
var
  sl1, sl2: TStrings;
  i: Integer;
begin
  with Form1 do
  begin
    sl1 := TStringList.Create;
    sl2 := TStringList.Create;
    sl1.Text := Memo1.Text;
    for i := 0 to sl1.Count div 2 do
    begin
      sl2.Insert(i, sl1.Strings[i]);
      srtli[1] := sl2.Text;
    end;
    Memo2.Lines.Add(srtli[1]);
    sl2.Free;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Comment: Используйте сортировку, а не тупой перебор. IndexOf при сортированном списке использует дихотомический поиск. То есть для миллиона записей не более 20 итераций.С потоками я бы не парился.

Comment: Кстати beginupdate endupdate при выводе в мемо обязателен

Comment: Простите, не могли бы вы привести пример с сортировкой. Заморочился с потоками так как хотел понять как работает это дело и решить свою задачу, так сказать двух зайцев одним выстрелом.

Comment: У TStringlist есть метод sort. Скопировать в него данные можно методами AddStrings или assign, чтобы данные в TMemo не портились. Есть нюанс со страницей кодировки. То есть создаем 3 объекта sl1 := TstringList.Create; затем добавляем в первый и второй строки из TMemo. Sl1.Addstrings(memo1.lines) . Затем Sl1.Sort; а потом в цикле смотрим что из списка Sl1 есть в Sl2.  if Sl2.IndexOf(Sl1[i]) = -1 then; Результат добавляем в третий список. Возможно у Вас тормоза были главные из-за отсутствия BeginUpdate, при каждом добавление в результирующее мемо шла перерисовка.

Comment: Можно оптимизировать задачу, сортировать только один список кстати, только вот какой именно, что-то не соображу (меньший или больший из двух.) Ну а уж если хочется потоков, то можно было бы разбить на кучу TStringList по первой букве.